# Pandas merge using date interval and compute sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have two dataframes

`master`df looks like below

```
Pid sid   Date_1     Date_2     Qty
1   101  1/1/2017   1/1/2018    200
1   102  1/2/2018   1/2/2019    150
2   101  3/3/2017   3/3/2018    300
2   102  9/9/2019   9/9/2020    1000
3   105  8/8/2018   11/11/2021  700
```

`order` df looks like below

```
Pro_id  skid     Orqty  Date_3
1       101      100    1/3/2019
1       102      200    3/3/2020
1       103      50     2/2/2019
1       101      50     1/2/2015
2       101      200    5/5/2019
2       102      200    2/7/2021
2       102      100    2/5/2021
2       102      100    2/11/2021
```

I would like to

a) merge `master` and `order` based on columns - `pid==pro_id` AND `sid==skid` AND `date_3` > `date_2`

b) Compute sum of the `Orqty` for each `pid` and `sid`.

c) Attach last value of `date_3` column for every `pid` and `sid` combination

I was trying something like below to achive the date logic

```
pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(order['date_3'], master['date_2'], closed='both') #option 1

df = join(master, order, on=[pid,sid])    #option 2
df[df[:,:date_1].>=df[:,:date_2].<= df[:,:date_3],:]
```

Can you help me with the below?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Is `2/11/2021`  - `2. November` or `11.February` ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert values to datetimes and then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), filter by `date`s with aggregate `sum` and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df1['Date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_1'], dayfirst=True)
df1['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_2'], dayfirst=True)
df2['Date_3'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date_3'], dayfirst=True)


df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Pid','sid'], right_on=['Pro_id','skid'])

df = (df[df['Date_3'].gt(df['Date_2'])]
       .groupby(['Pid','sid'], as_index=False)
       .agg(Qty = ('Qty', 'last'),
            Orqty = ('Orqty', 'sum'),
            last_order_date = ('Date_3', 'last')))
print (df)
   Pid  sid   Qty  Orqty last_order_date
0    1  101   200    100      2019-03-01
1    1  102   150    200      2020-03-03
2    2  101   300    200      2019-05-05
3    2  102  1000    400      2021-11-02
```

If need filter between 2 datetimes in one line solution:

```
df1['Date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_1'], dayfirst=True)
df1['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_2'], dayfirst=True)
df2['Date_3'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date_3'], dayfirst=True)


df = (df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Pid','sid'], right_on=['Pro_id','skid'])
         .query('Date_1 <= Date_2 <= Date_3')
         .groupby(['Pid','sid'], as_index=False)
         .agg(Qty = ('Qty', 'last'),
              Orqty = ('Orqty', 'sum'),
              last_order_date = ('Date_3', 'last')))
print (df)
   Pid  sid   Qty  Orqty last_order_date
0    1  101   200    100      2019-03-01
1    1  102   150    200      2020-03-03
2    2  101   300    200      2019-05-05
3    2  102  1000    400      2021-11-02
```

Comment: may I know why do we have to do `agg(Qty = ('Qty', 'sum'))`? We have to sum only `Orqty`

Comment: @TheGreat - sure, I can explain. Because if omit it also is omited column `Qty` in ouput DataFrame. And from expected output seems need `Qty` (If understand correct)

Comment: Yes, we need `Qty` column but should not sum..For ex: last row with `pid = 2` and `sid = 102`, should only be `1000` and not `3000`

Comment: @TheGreat - Understand, then need `last` instead `sum`, answer was eidted.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there any dummy method like `agg(Qty = ('Qty', 'NA'))`? So, it doesn't do any operation but just retains as is. Yes, last also work but was curious to know

Comment: @TheGreat - it is aggregation, so not.